# Peltier and Portable Litium Ion Battery

Tags: lithium-ion, peltier

I am designing a portable rechargeable heat flask using peltier module at what specifications I should choose my power supply?? I am actually going for rechargeable lithium Ion battery with 12 volt and 6800mah whether that might be useful

Comment: (1) "What specifications should I use for my power supply?" "I am actually going for ..." Welcome to EE.SE. If you've already decided then why are you asking? (2) Why are you using Peltier for heating rather than a resistive element? (3) Have you performed your required energy calculations? (Volume, initial temperature, final temperature and time to heat.) Post these details **in your original question** and not in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

It depends directly on how much heat you want to transfer and how fast you want to do it. It also depends on the module's power capacity.

You need to make some calculations on that first. Is not only a rule of thumb thing.